# NP-completeness of satisfiability of formula over 50 variables

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

Given a boolean formula $F$ of length $n$ defined over a fixed number of variables (say 50), is it NP-complete to decide whether $F$ is satisfiable?

Comment: @Pål GD its problem just induce from when i was thinking about SAT problem, SAT problem describe $n$ variables. so i wonder if its can be fixed variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of variables, then you have a fixed number of assignments $2^{|\text{vars}|}$, so there's a polynomial time algorithm for checking all possible assignments.

Comment: Though the length of boolean formula is random?

Comment: i think i got it,  $2^{|\text{vars}|}n$, the $2^{|\text{vars}|}$ is constant. thanks!

Comment: In fact, linear time.

Comment: In fact, constant time.

Comment: @JohnColeman No, you still have to read the $n$ long formula, which takes time at least $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: @PålGD You are correct. I misread OP as fixing all the parameters.